# Adobe Premiere Pro CS4 freezes on startup

Tags: adobe-premiere, adobe-cs4

Not sure if anyone else has experienced this, but every time i start up Premiere Pro CS4 it basically freezes after the splash screen finishes.  Any suggestions for diagnosing this issue?

Comment: OS      version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adobe has some very detailed articles on troubleshooting freezing issues and a myriad of other things with Premiere, you can find it [here](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/408/kb408983.html) (Vista) or [here](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/405/kb405950.html) (XP).

If none of that helps whatsoever, check the running process with [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to see what exactly it is doing on startup. A [defrag](http://www.defraggler.com/), [cclean](http://www.ccleaner.com/), and virus scan wouldn't hurt much either.